# Extracting financial years overlapping with tenancy periods

Tags: sql, db2

Given these tenancy contracts:

```
          2012        2013        2014        2015        2016
YR        |           |           |           |           |     
FIN_YR       | 2012-2013 | 2013-2014 | 2014-2015 | 2015-2016 |     
          ____________________________________________________
1         ----------------++++--------------------------------
2         -----+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------
4         -----------------------------++++++++++++++++++-----
```

which lasted over these dates:

```
TENANCY_ID FROM       TO
---------- ---------- ----------
1          2013-05-02 2013-08-12
2          2012-06-22 2015-09-01
4          2014-06-03 2015-11-15
```

I want to produce a long table like:

```
TENANCY_ID Financial_Year
---------- --------------
1          2013-2014
2          2012-2013
2          2013-2014
2          2014-2015
2          2015-2016
4          2014-2015
4          2015-2016
```

where `Financial_Year` shows the financial years (1 Apr - 31 Mar) over which each  tenancy, at least partly, lasted.

If relevant, [db2](/questions/tagged/db2), otherwise a generic solution would be fine.

Comment: Hello, have You a list of financial years somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in a table (year INT).

Comment: If year = 2013, it's 2012-2013, or 2013-2014 ?

Comment: 2013 --> 2013-2014

Comment: Edited my answer below

Comment: This breaks down into two pieces: 1) generating the year->start/end mapping table, like @Razzka does (frankly, a `Calendar` table, which would include things like financial year start, and about a billion other things, is one of the most useful analysis tables you can have in a db).  2) a simple, solved, [overlapping date range check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/812837).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, haven't got db2 at hand, here's example at Oracle:

```
with financial_years as (
      select to_char(r) || '-' || to_char(r + 1) as year, 
             to_date('01.04.' || to_char(r),'dd.mm.yyyy') as date_begin, 
             to_date('31.03.' || to_char(r + 1) || '23:59:59','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date_End
      from t_fin_year -- here's a table (year INT)
    )
    select y.year,
           t.id
    from t_tenancy t
    join financial_years y
      on y.date_begin between t.from and t.to
         OR y.date_end between t.from and t.to
    order by t.id, y.year;
```

The main idea is to join financial years with tenancy wia dates: if year start or end is between tenancy start\end, then tenancy belongs to this year.

Comment: First, dates should never use inclusive upper bounds (`<=`), but exclusive ones (`<`), especially if the precision of the type can vary (for example - timestamps on pretty much all RDBMSs allow you to specify the number of decimal places for fractional seconds).  So, never use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp types.  Second, this actually _doesn't_ return the correct results for tenancies with multiple (more than 2) years, since in those cases there are years in the middle that aren't part of the start/end data.